# JQuery вообще не работает! В чем может быть проблема? Выставляю весь код? помогите

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```html
<div class="index-container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="index_block">
          <div class="header_slider">
            <script type="mce-text/javascript" src="{{skin url=''}}js/camera.js"></script>
            <script type="mce-text/javascript">
              // <![CDATA[
              /* index slider */
              jQuery(function() {
                jQuery('#camera_wrap').camera({
                  alignmen: 'topCenter',
                  height: '38.461%',
                  minHeight: '50px',
                  loader: false,
                  navigation: false,
                  fx: 'simpleFade',
                  navigationHover: false,
                  thumbnails: false,
                  playPause: false
                });
              });
               // ]]>
            </script>
            <div class="fluid_container">
              <div id="camera_wrap" class="camera_wrap camera_orange_skin">
                <div data-src="{{skin url=''}}images/slider_pic1.jpg" data-link="specials.html">
                  <div class="camera_caption fadeIn">
                    <div class="right_slider_side sl_1">
                      <h2>Материнские платы</h2>
                      <p>&nbsp;</p>
                      <h4>восстановленные</h4>
                      <h4>&nbsp;</h4>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div data-src="{{skin url=''}}images/slider_pic2.jpg" data-link="tripods.html">
                <div class="camera_caption fadeIn">
                  <div class="right_slider_side sl_2">
                    <h2>Сервера IBM и HP&nbsp;&nbsp;</h2>
                    <h4>International Business Machines</h4>
                    <h4>Hewlett-Packard</h4>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div data-src="{{skin url=''}}images/slider_pic3.jpg" data-link="video-cameras.html">
          <div class="camera_caption fadeIn">
            <div class="right_slider_side sl_3">
              <h2>Ноутбуки</h2>
              <h4>восстановленные</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Кто знает помогите очень сильно надо!

Comment: Напишите какую строчку удалили, где удалили, что должно было получиться и что получилось. А то куча кода и "ааааа, я всё сломал, ничего не знаю"

Comment: <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div> Думаю что в етой строке. Пробовал сам менять не получается ничего.

Comment: на фото видно где было 3 слайда менял текст на слайдах удалил даже сам не заментил как

Comment: <div data-src="{{skin url=''}}images/slider_pic3.jpg" data-link="video-cameras.html">
          <div class="camera_caption fadeIn">
            <div class="right_slider_side sl_3">
              <h2>Ноутбуки</h2>
              <h4>восстановленные</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>

Comment: @Женя дайте ссылку на Ваш сайт

Comment: https://3r.com.ua

Answer (score 2):

Перенес блок:

```
<div data-src="{{skin url=''}}images/slider_pic3.jpg" data-link="video-cameras.html">
<div class="camera_caption fadeIn">
    <div class="right_slider_side sl_3">
        <h2>Ноутбуки</h2>
        <h4>восстановленные</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

ниже, чем он должен быть. Он должен идти сразу за:

```
<div data-src="{{skin url=''}}images/slider_pic2.jpg" data-link="tripods.html">
<div class="camera_caption fadeIn">
    <div class="right_slider_side sl_2">
        <h2>Сервера IBM и HP&nbsp;&nbsp;</h2>
        <h4>International Business Machines</h4>
        <h4>Hewlett-Packard</h4>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
</div>
```